# sql request GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. The first contains a list of groups. The second contains the time of publication of posts.
You need to get a list of groups, and post to them, but the posts should be sorted by time.
When I do in the grouping, then the time of fasting is not the same.

```
            table time_post
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+
| id |  id_public    | img_id | time_post |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |             1 |      2 |         5 |
|  2 |             2 |      1 |         1 |
|  7 |             1 |      1 |        55 |
|  8 |             1 |      3 |         2 |
| 10 |             3 |      3 |         4 |
| 11 |             3 |      3 |         2 |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+

     table public
+----+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| id | id_public | time_update | access_token | text_send |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |      9876 |           0 | 1234         |           |
|  2 |     12345 |           0 | 12345        |           |
|  3 |     22222 |           0 |              |           |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
                 To get this result
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| id_public | time_post   | access_token | text_send |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
|      9876 |           2 | 1234         |           |
|     12345 |           1 | 12345        |           |
|     22222 |           2 |              |           |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

time_post should be sorted by the minimum

Comment: add your expected output for better answer

Comment: Your question could do with a bit of work for examples -1)'The first contains a list of groups'. - there is nothing called group in the first table, 2)There does not appear to be any relationship between the data in time_posts and public,  2) 'time of fasting' what's that then?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: There is no way you can get that result from that data since there is no relationship between the 2 tables.

Comment: And what can I do to get such a result?

Comment: a foreign key would suffice

Comment: He is in my  table

Comment: How to first sort by time_post, and then group. I do like this http://rgho.st/8LHx66ZQr

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id_public,tp.time_post,p.access_token,p.text_send  
FROM time_post tp 
INNER JOIN public p
ON tp.id_public=p.id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM time_post GROUP BY id_public) AS T
ON tp.id=T.id
ORDER BY p.id_public
```

**Output**

```
id_public   time_post   access_token    text_send
9876        2           1234            (null)
12345       1           12345           (null)
22222       2           (null)          (null)
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbb18/6

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p.id_public,min(t.time_post),p.access_token,p.text_send
FROM public as p ,time_post as t
WHERE p.id = t.id_public
group by p.id_public,p.access_token,p.text_send

Try this,I hope it's working.

For demo link,
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/46M8v9opAeVc834tZ15Vur/0#&togetherjs=nRGqfr7bdE